# Dynamically add image and hover event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a way to dynamically add image with some hover function . thanks .

```
<ul id="imagesList">
  <li>No images found</li>
</ul>

$(function(){
            //load image array
            var images = {'image1':'assets/img/linkedin_30px.png','image2':'assets/img/twitter_30px.png'};
            $.each(images, function(){
               ....?
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into [event delgation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). That way you can have the event handler assinged in one place, and have it work with changing domnodes. It could look like something like this in your case:

```
$('#imagesList').on('hover', 'img', function(){
    // your hover event handler here
});
```

Then you can create the image nodes:

```
$('#imagesList').html('');
var images = {'image1':'assets/img/linkedin_30px.png','image2':'assets/img/twitter_30px.png'};
$.each(images, function(i, src){
    $('#imagesList').append('<li><img src="'+src+'"></li>');
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pwGQX/

Answer (score 0):

I would need more details but quickly, you can use jQuery's .hover event;

```
    $("#imagesList").hover(
      // prepend the image on hover
      function() {
          $( this ).prepend( $( "<span><img src='image-x.jpg'></span>" ) );
        },
      // Remove the image when mouse leaves
        function() {
          $( this ).find( "span:first" ).remove();
      }
    );
```